# Geofence Notification

Tags: android, google-maps, android-geofence

I am working on google geofence. I want to implement feature like UBER - when I enter or exit 100 meter radius, notification will come. I am getting the latitude and longitude from google places api which will be my geofence. Here is my MapActivity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
String Longitude, Latitude;
Location ll;
final String TAG = "GPS";
private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2 * 1000;  /* 10 secs */
private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 2000; /* 2 sec */
static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
GoogleApiClient gac;
LocationRequest locationRequest;


int PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment;
Marker markerDesti, markerCurrentLoc;
LatLng DestiLoc;
double LatDesti, latCurrent;
double LonDesti, lngCurrent;

private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 2;
String mPermission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
PendingIntent mGeofencePendingIntent;
ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
private GeofencingClient mGeofencingClient;

TextView TestBtn;

LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

private GeofancingResultCallBack geofancingResultCallBack;


public static final class Constants {
    public static int GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS = 1000;
    public static int GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    TestBtn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TestBtn);

    isGooglePlayServicesAvailable();
    if (!isLocationEnabled())
        showAlert();

    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    gac = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();


    //========================= PLACES API DROP DOWN============================//


    mGeofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);
    mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<>();


}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    getPlacesApi();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    gac.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    gac.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        updateUI(location);

    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        return;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected");

    ll = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(gac);
    Log.d(TAG, "LastLocation: " + (ll == null ? "NO LastLocation" : ll.toString()));
    Log.e("MYLatLonLocationService", ll.toString());
    Latitude = Double.toString(ll.getLatitude());
    Longitude = Double.toString(ll.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Latitude + "\n" + Longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("Lat&Lon", Latitude + "\n" + Longitude);

    latCurrent = ll.getLatitude();
    lngCurrent = ll.getLongitude();
    LatLng locCurrent = new LatLng(latCurrent, lngCurrent);
    markerCurrentLoc = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(locCurrent)
            .title("My Location"));
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(gac, locationRequest, this);
}


//=========== DRAW CURRENT LOCATION==============//
private void drawAllMarker() {

    LatLng locCurrent = new LatLng(latCurrent, lngCurrent);
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(locCurrent).title("My Location"));

    markerCurrentLoc = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(locCurrent)
            .title("My Location"));
    /*mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(locCurrent));
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
            locCurrent).zoom(13).build();
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));*/
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(gac, locationRequest, this);
}


//=========== onRequestPermissionsResult ==============//
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
        int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Permission was granted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                try {
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                            gac, locationRequest, this);
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "SecurityException:\n" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Permission denied!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "onConnectionFailed: \n" + connectionResult.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("DDD", connectionResult.toString());
}

private void updateUI(Location loc) {
    Log.d(TAG, "updateUI");

    /*tvLatitude.setText(Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()));
    tvLongitude.setText(Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()));
    tvTime.setText(DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(loc.getTime()));*/

    TestBtn.setText(Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()));


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling

        return;
    }
    ll = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(gac);
    Log.d(TAG, "LastLocation: " + (ll == null ? "NO LastLocation" : ll.toString()));
    Log.e("MYLatLonLocationService", ll.toString());
    Latitude = Double.toString(ll.getLatitude());
    Longitude = Double.toString(ll.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Latitude + "\n" + Longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("Lat&Lon", Latitude + "\n" + Longitude);

    if (markerCurrentLoc != null) {
        markerCurrentLoc.remove();

        latCurrent = ll.getLatitude();
        lngCurrent = ll.getLongitude();
        LatLng locCurrent = new LatLng(latCurrent, lngCurrent);
        markerCurrentLoc = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(locCurrent)
                .title("My Location"));
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                locCurrent).zoom(12).build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(gac, locationRequest, this);

    }else {


        latCurrent = ll.getLatitude();
        lngCurrent = ll.getLongitude();
        LatLng locCurrent = new LatLng(latCurrent, lngCurrent);
        markerCurrentLoc = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(locCurrent)
                .title("My Location"));
        markerCurrentLoc = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(locCurrent)
                .title("My Location"));
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                locCurrent).zoom(12).build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(gac, locationRequest, this);
    }
}

private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
            locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "This device is supported.");
    return true;
}

private void showAlert() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Enable Location")
            .setMessage("Your Locations Settings is set to 'Off'.\nPlease Enable Location to " +
                    "use this app")
            .setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                }
            });
    dialog.show();
}

//=========================== PLACES API=======================//

public void getPlacesApi() {

    autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());


            if (markerDesti != null) {
                markerDesti.remove();

                LatDesti = place.getLatLng().latitude;
                LonDesti = place.getLatLng().longitude;
                Log.e("LatLonDest", String.valueOf(LatDesti));
                DestiLoc = new LatLng(LatDesti, LonDesti);
                markerDesti = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(DestiLoc)
                        .title("My Destination"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(DestiLoc));
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                        DestiLoc).zoom(12).build();
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                        .setRequestId("120")
                        .setCircularRegion(
                                LatDesti,
                                LonDesti,
                                Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                        )
                        .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
                        .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                                Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                        .build());

                //geofancingResultCallBack.regesterAllGeofance();
                //geofancingResultCallBack.myUpdateGeoFance(LatDesti, LonDesti);
                //geofancingResultCallBack.getGeofencingRequest();
                //geofancingResultCallBack.getmPendingIntent();


            } else {

                LatDesti = place.getLatLng().latitude;
                LonDesti = place.getLatLng().longitude;
                Log.e("LatLonDest", String.valueOf(LatDesti));
                DestiLoc = new LatLng(LatDesti, LonDesti);
                markerDesti = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(DestiLoc)
                        .title("My Destination"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(DestiLoc));
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                        DestiLoc).zoom(12).build();
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                        .setRequestId("120")
                        .setCircularRegion(
                                LatDesti,
                                LonDesti,
                                Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                        )
                        .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
                        .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                                Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                        .build());

                //geofancingResultCallBack.regesterAllGeofance();
                //geofancingResultCallBack.myUpdateGeoFance(LatDesti, LonDesti);
                //geofancingResultCallBack.getGeofencingRequest();
                //geofancingResultCallBack.getmPendingIntent();


            }

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling

                return;
            }
            mGeofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(MapsActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            // Geofences added
                            Log.e("Geofencing Location service Api Client", "successfully added");

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(MapsActivity.this, new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            // Failed to add geofences
                            Log.e("Geofencing Location service Api Client", "unsuccessful");
                        }
                    });

            //============================================================================================//

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //autocompleteFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
            Log.i(TAG, "Place:" + place.toString());
        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
            Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());
        } else if (requestCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

        }
    }
}


//============================== GEO FANCING=================================//

private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}
private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
    if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BroadcastReciver.class);
    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when
    // calling addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
    mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.
            FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return mGeofencePendingIntent;
}
```

}

and my broadcast receiver is

```
public class BroadcastReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

//Placer Geofence intent action name
public static final String INTENT_ACTION_TRIGGER_FIRED = "com.placer.action.TRIGGER_FIRED";
public static final String TAG1 = GeofanceBroadCastReciver.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String TAG = "GeofenceTransitions";

public BroadcastReciver() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    /*GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()){

        Log.e(TAG,String.format("Error code :%d",geofencingEvent.getErrorCode()));
        return;
    }

    int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
    if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER){
        Log.e("Geo Fance ENTER","Geo Fance ENTER");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Geo Fance ENTER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }else if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT){
        Log.e("Geo Fance EXIT","Geo Fance EXIT");
        Toast.makeText(context,"Geo Fance EXIT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else {

        Log.e(TAG,String.format("Unknown Transition :%",geofenceTransition));
        return;
    }

    sendNotification(context,geofenceTransition);*/


    if (intent.getAction().equals(INTENT_ACTION_TRIGGER_FIRED)) {

    Log.e("ReciverWorking","ReciverWorking");
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Goefencing Error " + geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
        return;
    }
    // Get the transition type.
    int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
    Log.i(TAG, "geofenceTransition = " + geofenceTransition + " Enter : " + Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER + "Exit : " + Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT);
    if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER || geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL){
        showNotification("Congrats!!!", "You have reached your destination..",context);
        Toast.makeText(context,"Enter the Location",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Showing Notification...");
        showNotification("Exited", "Exited the Location",context);
        Toast.makeText(context,"Exited the Location",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        // Log the error.
        showNotification("Error", "Error",context);
        Log.e(TAG, "Error ");
    }

    }else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
private void sendNotification(Context context,int transationType){

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,MapsActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MapsActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    PendingIntent notificationpendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    if (transationType == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER){
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentTitle("Entered");
    }else if (transationType == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentTitle("Exit");
    }

    builder.setContentText("Touch to launch the app");
    builder.setContentIntent(notificationpendingIntent);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}




public void showNotification(String text, String bigText,Context context) {
    // 1. Create a NotificationManager
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // 2. Create a PendingIntent for AllGeofencesActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // 3. Create and send a notification
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Congrats!!!")
            .setContentText("You Have reached the destination")
            .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(bigText))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

}
```

the Android Manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".main.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".adapters.GeofenceTransitionsIntentService"
        android:exported="true" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.map.pallabedp.locationbasedtracking.main.BroadcastReciver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.placer.action.TRIGGER_FIRED" />
            <action android:name="my.action.string" />
            <action android:name="com.map.pallabedp.locationbasedtracking.main.BroadcastReciver"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

The problem is i am not getting any notification. Please help..

Comment: Not your direct problem, but `public class BroadcastReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {` is a naming choice bound to trip you up sooner or later.

Comment: Ok, I have changed the name now..